# cran studio does not have a release faile

Tags: 18.04, rstudio

When I run: `sudo apt-get update`

I get the below error:

> E: The repository 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/
>   Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a
>   repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
>   default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>   configuration details.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: Kindly mention the version of Ubuntu in the question!

Comment: That software source supports trusty (14.04) & xenial (16.04), it looks to me like you're using bionic (18.04) *but didn't tell us*, which is a release that isn't supported by that source.  I just noticed it uses non-Ubuntu names for bionic, *bionic-cran35* so you must use that i guess

Comment: @Kulfy, Thankyou!! Learned new thing today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a simple mistake when adding cran to your sources.

It's not `bionic/`
It is `bionic-cran35/`

One way to discover the correct entry is by merely opening the URL.

Comment: I am a complete newbie, I followed a tutorial I think. How can I modify my sources from bionic/ to bionic-cran35/  ?

Comment: Cannot find it, I did it months ago. I do not know what 'sources' mean, if it's a linux or Rstudio thing. What is the command to check my sources?

Comment: You download *software* in a deb or snap *package* from a *source* repository someplace on the internet. These sources are listed in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ Browse through those until you find your cran source(s). Then edit your question above to show us exactly which file has the cran source and the complete contents of that file. Are you still using cran? Or are you trying to remove it? Have you been having this error for months?